# Can the 74LVC06A input be connected to an open-drain output?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, open-drain

[image: 74LS06]

The picture above is the SN74LS06 schematic from Texas Instruments. It appears that the input of the SN74LS06 can be connected to an open-drain output.

I purchased the 74LVC06APW from Nexperia. But I don't get any message about design unity.

Are all 74LVC06 and 74LS06 devices compatible? Can I connect the input of the 74LVC06APW to an open-drain output? Or it is better to add a pull-up resistor?

Comment: The input of a 74LS06 will probably appear high when connected to a "High" open-drain or open collector output, but you should use a pull-up resistor to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must connect the open-drain driver to a pull-up resistor to drive the 74LVC06APW input.

The 74LVC06APW will output a tiny current (its input leakage current, IIK) but that will not pull strongly to the upper rail.

A pull-up of 10..47K should be plenty strong enough.

But the actual value will mainly be a function of the load capacitance and the switching frequency.

Comment: To be clear: this is true whether it's open-collector or open-drain. Logic inputs should never be left open-circuit, even if they have some natural pull-up tendency, like TTL does.

Comment: Nothing's unclear, @TimWilliams. The question and the answer are about a specific circuit, not the general case.